# Android: Adding side-by-side views to a tableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm currently adding a couple of TextViews and a Button to a new tableRow. It works fine, except that they get added vertically. How can you add them side-by-side?

This is what the code looks like:

```
public void submitAnswer(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder answer = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    answer.setTitle("Submit Question");
    answer.setMessage("Enter question: ");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    final TextView ans = new TextView(this);
    final TextView likeCount = new TextView(this);
    likeCount.setText("0");
    final Button likeButton = new Button(this);
    likeButton.setText("Like");
    answer.setView(input);

    answer.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();

            ans.setText(value);

            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.CSQ1answers);

            ans.setWidth(450);
            ans.setTextSize(20);

            likeButton.setTextSize(20);             
            likeCount.setTextSize(20);

            tl.addView(ans);
            tl.addView(likeButton);
            tl.addView(likeCount);
        }
    });

    answer.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        }
    });

    answer.show();

}
```

Comment: Hi, excuse me where do you use TableRow tr variable? I see it declared but not used after

Comment: Looks like that was my problem. I was adding each view to the table itself, rather than adding them to a row and adding the row to the table. I'm a moron

Comment: Ahah ok, can you vote my comment and the answer I will write then? thanks I vote your answer too

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the TableRow tr, simply you doesn't use it. Use it and let us know if it works fine. Thanks